Unknown file analysis
I have a file, which supposedly contains an output of CRC32 hash. Problem is, file has no extension, type file (cat analogue) returns mangled gibberish, i.e. ёя╫жW▲{═Sb╨y¶|ИМ▐ВQ╙l9k╖▀у║?╩↓b☼┐R.
TrID said nothing on the matter:

Hex editor didn't reveal much:

Binvis.io byteclasses and entropy:


So, the question is: how can I check/know which encryption algo it uses (if any)?

Looks like compressed to me. Have you tried zlib.decompress(buf), just in case?

Yeah. it returned "unrecognized string format" . Binwalk also returned nothing, if you wondered.
